# Change background of a button when clicking another button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently experimenting in WPF and just created a UniformGrid with 800 buttons which are created in a for loop. All buttons have their own names and share the same click event. 
What I want to do now is the following: I want to click the first button (rect0) to change the color of this button and the next one (rect1).
I am totally stuck right now because everything I write into the click event refers to the button I clicked.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
        {
            Button BTN_rect = new Button()
            {
                Name = "rect" + i,
                Background = Brushes.White,          
            };
            BTN_rect.Click += BTN_rect_Click;
            Uniform.Children.Add(BTN_rect);
        }            
    }
    private void BTN_rect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button BTN_rect = sender as Button;

        BTN_rect.Background = Brushes.Red;
        MessageBox.Show(BTN_rect.Name);
    }
```

Comment: you could add tthe controls to a  `List<Button>` as you make them inside the loop, then use `yourButtons[yourButtons.IndexOf(BTN_rect)+1]` to access the next element

Comment: Don't do that. Seems like you try to use WPF as you would have do Winforms. That's a mistake. If you want to learn WPF, take an online course, read a good tutorial. WPF have binding capabilities that can only compare to winforms databind the same way you compare a Lamborghini to a donkey tied to a wagon. Don't make the same mistake I've made when I first started playing around in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

There are a load of ways to do this.
I took a shortcut and put just 9 buttons in a stackpanel, otherwise the same.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Button BTN_rect = new Button()
            {
                Name = "rect" + i,
                Content =Name,
                Tag = i,
                Background = Brushes.White,
            };
            BTN_rect.Click += BTN_rect_Click;
            sp.Children.Add(BTN_rect);
        }

    }
    private void BTN_rect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button current = sender as Button;
        current.Background = Brushes.Red;
        string targetName = $"rect{((int)current.Tag) + 1}";
        Button nextButton = sp.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == targetName).SingleOrDefault();
        nextButton.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
```

Usually, you'd template data into repeated controls rather than add them in code, btw.